# Can an indicator function be a valid Radon Nikodym derivative?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Take a process $X_t$ defined on a canonical space with probability $\mathbb{P}$. Can the indicator function $\mathbb{1}_{X_t< U}$ be a Radon Nikodym derivative? That is can we have a measure $\mathbb{Q}$ equivalent to $\mathbb{P}$ such that :

\begin{equation}
\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}=c\mathbb{1}_{\{X_t< U\}}
\end{equation}
where $c=E[\mathbb{1}_{X_t< U}]$?

My intuition says that because the indicator function will assign zero probability to some events, then  $\mathbb{Q}$ will not be absolutely continuous wrt $\mathbb{P}$, but am I right?

Any references are highly appreciated as well.Thank you.

Comment: The more zero $\mu$ is the easier it is for it to be absolutely continuous with respect to another measure $\nu$. You can check that $\mu(E)=\int_E f(x)d\nu(x)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$, in particular if $f=1_{A}$ is an indicator function.

Comment: But if you take the set $E=\{X>A\}$ which has a certain probability under $\nu$, ($\nu(E)\neq 0$) and the indicator $\mathbb{1}_{\{A\leq 0\}}$ then $\mu(E)=0$, so there is a null set that exists under $\mu$ but doesn't exist under $\nu$.

Comment: The definition is: $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$ is for every $E$ such that $\nu(E)=0$ we have $\mu(E)=0$. So, it is not a problem if $\mu(E)=0$ while $\nu(E)\neq0$.

Comment: Right. I get that. But from my reasoning above the two measures are not equivalent, that is the absolute continuity condition doesn't hold on both directions. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I totally skipped the word equivalent. For equivalence the derivative must be non-zero a.e. The indicator would work if and only if the complement of the set has measure zero.

Comment: Right, so for a general real number $A$ the indicator function $1_{\{x<A\}}$ can not define a another equivalent measure . However, we can have another measure $\mathbb{Q}$, which is not equivalent to $\mathbb{P}$ but is absolutely continous wrt it. Would that summarise our discussion?

Comment: The condition would be: $1_{x<A}$ gives an equivalent measure if and only if $P(X\geq A)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you fix $t$, $c1_{\{X_t<U\}}$, is a valid Radon-Nikodym derivative in the sense that you can define $\mathbb{Q}$ through the formula

$$\mathbb{Q}(A)=\int_Ac1_{\{X_t<U\}}d\mathbb{P}=c\mathbb{P}(A\cap\{X_t<U\}).$$

That is, $\mathbb{Q}$ is defined to be restriction of $\mathbb{P}$ to $\{X_t<U\}$ (times the constant $c$). Now, $\mathbb{Q}$ will in general not be equivalent to $\mathbb{P}$, this is only the case if they both have the same null sets. From the definition of $\mathbb{Q}$, every null set of $\mathbb{P}$ is one of $\mathbb{Q}$. The converse is true only if (assuming $c\neq0$) $\mathbb{P}$ has support in $\{X_t<U\}$ in which case $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ are really the same measure (modulo the constant).

By the way, if you'd like $\mathbb{Q}$ to be a probability measure, you should be choosing $c=1/\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{P}[1_{\{X_t<U\}}]$ and not $c=\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{P}[1_{\{X_t<U\}}]$.

Comment: Well summarised. Thanks.